# Delphi - Passing auth info to finviz with TIdHTTP

Tags: http, delphi, indy

I have Fiddler, and looking into Headers and Auth when I open `elite.finviz.com` in a browser, and nothing is showing up in there. In a browser, I enter my email and password in order to get auth-ed, any ideas how this should be implemented with `TIdHTTP`?

```http
CONNECT finviz.com:443 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
Host: finviz.com:443
```

These are the only request headers, and there is nothing in the Cookies tab, either.

There are two requests though, one to `finviz.com` and one to `elite.finviz.com`. Both have nothing in headers/auth/cookies though.

I am using `TIdHTTP` successfully to download the screener data in non-auth mode. I am not sure what I can try given the info above.

---

If I sign out in a browser, when I sent another request like `https://finviz.com/screener.ash`, it does not show up in a Fiddler at all...

---

Okay, now that I added HTTPS decryption, I can see the following cookie being passed.

I tried to Post login data with the following code:

```pascal
vParams := TStringList.Create;
try
  vParams.Add('email=myemail@gmail.com');
  vParams.Add('password=PwKypeuvY4nBBrg');
  vParams.Add('remember=true');

  //vUrl := 'https://finviz.com/login_submit.ashx';
  vUrl := 'https://finviz.com/login.ashx';

  vResult := FHTTP.Post(vUrl, vParams);

finally
  vParams.Free;
end
```

This seems to get through, but when I do `.Get` after that, I get the output that reflects that I am not logged in. I have set `FHTTP.AllowCookes` to TRUE and created a `TIdCookieManager`.

This is the cookie I see in Fiddler:

```http
Cookie:
 screenerUrl=screener.ashx%3Fv%3D111%26s%3Dta_unusualvolume%26f%3Dgeo_usa%2Cind_stocksonly%2Csh_curvol_o1000%2Csh_float_u50%2Csh_instown_o50%26o%3D-change;
 pv_date=Sun Mar 19 2023 05:44:22 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time);
 pv_count=8;
 _ga=GA1.2.1900518930.1672040178;
 _ga_ZT9VQEWD4N=GS1.1.1679227168.42.1.1679228660.0.0.0;
 euconsent-v2=CPokAsAPokAsAAKAuAENC7CsAP_AAH_AACRQJStd_H__bW9r-f5_aft0eY1P9_r77uQzDhfNk-4F3L_W_LwX52E7NF36tq4KmRYku1LBIUNlHNHUDVmwaokVryHsak2cpTNKJ6BEkHMZO2dYGF5vmxtj-QKY5_5_d3bx2D-t_9v-39z3z81Xnzd5_-_02PCdU5_9Dfn9fR_b89KP9_78v8v8_9_rk3_e__3_79_7_H9-YJRgEmGrcQBdmWODNoGEUCIEYVhIRQKACCgGFogIAHBwU7KwCfWECABAKAIwIgQYAowIBAAAJAEhEAEgRYIAAARAIAAQAIBEIAGBgEFgBYCAQAAgGgYohQACBIAZEBEUpgQFQJBAS2VCCUF0hphAFWWAFAIjYKABEEgIrAAEBYOAYIkBKxYIEmINogBGAFAKJUK1FJ6YAgAA.YAAAAAAAAAAA;
 _cmpRepromptHash=CPokAsAPokAsAAKAuAENC7CsAP_AAH_AACRQJStd_H__bW9r-f5_aft0eY1P9_r77uQzDhfNk-4F3L_W_LwX52E7NF36tq4KmRYku1LBIUNlHNHUDVmwaokVryHsak2cpTNKJ6BEkHMZO2dYGF5vmxtj-QKY5_5_d3bx2D-t_9v-39z3z81Xnzd5_-_02PCdU5_9Dfn9fR_b89KP9_78v8v8_9_rk3_e__3_79_7_H9-YJRgEmGrcQBdmWODNoGEUCIEYVhIRQKACCgGFogIAHBwU7KwCfWECABAKAIwIgQYAowIBAAAJAEhEAEgRYIAAARAIAAQAIBEIAGBgEFgBYCAQAAgGgYohQACBIAZEBEUpgQFQJBAS2VCCUF0hphAFWWAFAIjYKABEEgIrAAEBYOAYIkBKxYIEmINogBGAFAKJUK1FJ6YAgAA.YAAAAAAAAAAA.1.QjY0v9UMqYSBhGAhdjRltA%3D%3D;
 __qca=P0-477199397-1672040178363;
 _pbjs_userid_consent_data=3524755945110770;
 _pubcid=4390876f-44ab-4687-87f7-b5a77091d046;
 _lr_env_src_ats=false; 
 cto_bundle=jXM7_V9kSDJGZVpDNmo1MTdRdGRjJTJGWUJWQmFzZHVMazBSb1NLc0Z4ZEY0UlEwRDAlMkZHMU9nU2VtSmdQTkVkRUpQUEcyeUZaJTJGWDRZVmhBSU5DRk9id2F3JTJCajclMkZwSTNuNGxDR000Z1NtVlpETTU0Nk9Kc3k5QUFReE5Relc3anIxUlBKQkIlMkZjU09lNnZMMWclMkZtcDFVTHVPVSUyRjNBJTNEJTNE;
 cto_bidid=buwSIl9jcm5zQzZKWVFNdjA2dWVpVGdBMWptWVRXSlNVc1dxTHJYRGJ2UkdUdXpDbDRWNlU5Q3d5WUtPa2JBUTh0anB1ak5TbUtQMkZHV3V3UzNyU2huZEdyQW16c3hqN1RSWkI2SjZ6eWQ2SzRBcyUzRA;
 _cc_id=3851a38b41fecfb1b75cf8c672bbf524;
 kppid_managed=kppidff_PR96YttR;
 __gads=ID=9068bd2334312ccc-22edbf7e6ada00a5:T=1672054064:S=ALNI_MaMYebeLZz6gdp_a6ZJSAgGLowDtw;
 __gpi=UID=00000b985b9d4c45:T=1672054064:RT=1679219067:S=ALNI_MZ6QVpI7BmANph3Mf5XVbAeErAiNg;
 _awl=2.1679228357.5-d8e0cfa9986bd18e3fb9a7d06fab0e5f-6763652d6575726f70652d7765737431-0;
 _admrla=2.2-f5d86303bab16b87-58886f02-8510-11ed-81f2-2d92ac747379;
 cnx_userId=fade9bf0862147f583ab01bbe961c045;
 cto_dna_bundle=6HjcRF80M0RITmhlJTJCZkMwOUJGQlhaMUN2c3lCNWhvRjNnNHVFd3NGNmdFalBIbiUyRmZWblczeW94ZnhFbTJ5WWUlMkZpVCUyQkw;
 pbjs-unifiedid=%7B%22TDID_LOOKUP%22%3A%22FALSE%22%2C%22TDID_CREATED_AT%22%3A%222023-02-24T18%3A07%3A22%22%7D;
 _gid=GA1.2.1479033323.1678721017;
 _gd_visitor=d14d11c2-1918-494a-81f4-dffb718411d1;
 _an_uid=0;
 _gd_svisitor=1c92645f604d000001400f64db010000a0340100;
 panoramaId_expiry=1679243421863;
 customColors=%7B%22light%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22dark%22%3A%7B%7D%7D;
 _ga_9T4RBK8XLD=GS1.1.1679227168.5.1.1679228334.0.0.0;
 _gd_session=858d86b1-e914-4cce-89f4-7e25bf449bd6;
 _lr_retry_request=true
```

Comment: 'nothing is showing up' - maybe you did not configure Fiddler correctly. Is there no HTTP response for the first HTTP? You can also use the browser developer mode to view requests and responses.

Comment: Definitely use the browser's built-in debugger to see the requests it is sending, you don't need to use Fiddler at all

Comment: Thankx Ryan and Remy, I now see everything in Fiddler, I do see the Headers, Cookies and everything, I am just not sure how to put it into TIdHTTP to get the same result as in the browser. I was trying to Post login, which gets through, I added CookieManager expecting it to handle cookies automatically, but it did not work.

Comment: @GabrielleGoldberg "*I am just not sure how to put it into TIdHTTP to get the same result as in the browser*" - can't answer that without seeing the actual HTTP request(s) that the browser is sending. "*I added CookieManager expecting it to handle cookies automatically, but it did not work*" - assuming you are using the same `TIdHTTP`/`TIdCookieManager` object for multiple requests, then that would likely mean either `TIdCookieManager` rejected the cookie to begin with, or the cookie does not match the subsequent URLs being requested.